# Quartile function is right continuous?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions

This is a question from Erhan Cinlar's Probability and Stochastics Chapter 1 Section 5.13

Let $c$ be an increasing right-continuous function from $\mathbb{R}_+$ into $\bar{\mathbb{R}}_+$. Define

$a(u)=\inf\{t\in\mathbb{R}_+:c(t)>u\}$, $u\in\mathbb{R}_+$,

with the usual convention that $\inf\emptyset=\infty$.

Show that the function $a:\mathbb{R}_+\mapsto\bar{\mathbb{R}}_+$ is increasing and right-continuous.

I already done the increasing part. I got stuck at right-continuous.

Here is my attempt:

Given $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}u_n=u$ and $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$, $u_{n+1}\leq u_{n}$

$\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$ let $a(u_n)=t_n$

$\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$, $t_{n+1}\leq t_{n}$, since $a$ is increasing function.

$\exists t\in\mathbb{R}_+$, $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}t_n=t$, since $t_n$ is decreasing sequence and bounded below by $a(u)$

Suppose $t<a(u)$,

Suppose $c(t)>u$,

Let $A_u=\{t\in\mathbb{R}_+:c(t)>u\}$

$\Rightarrow$ $t\in A_u$, since $t\geq 0$

$\Rightarrow$ $t\geq a(u)$, by definition of $\inf$ and $a$

$\rightarrow\leftarrow$

Thus $c(t)\leq u$

$\Rightarrow$ $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} c(t_n)\leq u$, by right continuity of $c$

Then I am stuck. Please help me.

---

I found this paper that gives an answer, just put it here so that people can find it:
https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/b446/2321f432291c809dda1ab5fc224b4d1072ff.pdf

However, there is a step in the paper that i do not understand on the proof of Theorem 2:

> Suppose not. Then there exists $x_0$ and $h$ such that $F^{-1}_4(x^+_0)>h>F^{-1}_4(x_0)$. Then $F(h)>x_0$

How does the strict greater than hold in $F(h)>x_0$? Is it due to $h>F^{-1}_4(x_0)\implies F(h)>F(F^{-1}_4(x_0))$? Then it would require $F$ to be strictly increasing function, not just nondecreasing? Sorry I really dun understand that step?

Comment: I could solve the problem if $c$ was strictly increasing (not non-decreasing), but the question was not clear... Do you think he meant that $c$ strictly increasing?

Answer (score 1):

I found this paper that gives an answer, just put it here so that people can find it:
https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/b446/2321f432291c809dda1ab5fc224b4d1072ff.pdf

However, there is a step in the paper that i do not understand on the proof of Theorem 2:

> Suppose not. Then there exists $x_0$ and $h$ such that $F^{-1}_4(x^+_0)>h>F^{-1}_4(x_0)$. Then $F(h)>x_0$

How does the strict greater than hold in $F(h)>x_0$? Is it due to $h>F^{-1}_4(x_0)\implies F(h)>F(F^{-1}_4(x_0))$? Then it would require $F$ to be strictly increasing function, not just nondecreasing? Sorry I really dun understand that step?

---

On this paper, there is a good proof of left-continuity on another variety of generalized inverse, it could be adapted for this variety of generalized inverse to prove right-continuity:
[A note on generalized inverse](https://people.math.ethz.ch/%7Eembrecht/ftp/generalized_inverse.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

You almost have the proof. In your terms, you are trying to show that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a(u_n) = a(u)$. Now, we are going to show two related inequalities:

- $\lim a(u_n) \geq a(u)$: This follows from the monotonicity that that
  you said you proved.
- Let $\epsilon > 0$ be arbitrary. Then let's show $a(u_N) \leq a(u) + \epsilon$ for a sufficiently large $N$. (This is dubbed "giving yourself an epsilon of room" in Terry Tao's blog). So, we have that $c(t_n) \geq u_n$ and as you crucially observed, $t_n$ converge to $t = a(u)$. In particular, there is some $n$ such that $t + \epsilon \geq t_n$. Thus, we have $c(t + \epsilon) \geq u_n$ by monotonicity of $c$. Rearranging, we get what we want.

You can then conclude what you want by taking $\epsilon$ to 0.

Comment: Thank you for your hints, it gave me some directions. What if $c(t)>u$? Does it also give $t\leq a(u)$ ? Or does it lead to a contradiction?